# Google Analytics multiple codes

Tags: google-analytics

Normally when I add a html piece to my site, it will create a box that lets me know it's there. It' finicky though and the box didnt show up. So I added the html again, and it didnt tell me it was there. So I published the website and then went to a few pages to see if it worked. It did, and now each page is being tracked multiple times. Then I had the bright idea to redo the tracking code and add that hoping the new code would only be seen once. Not only is it picking up the new code, but the old one as well. Each pageview is being seen as three.

And like I said, my html builder blocks are not showing up on my builder, so I cant get rid of them. Is there a way I can fix this, or do I have to delete my whole file and re-do my analytics? If so, can anyone help me do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tracking code show the real time data or the data of past day.
So if anyone has the above mentioned issue, he need to wait at least 24 hours to get correct reporting through Google Analytic.